# OG tags not working with react-helmet and Netlify

Tags: prerender, netlify, facebook-opengraph, react-helmet

I cannot for the life of me figure this out. The following site is hosted on Netlify and prerendering is enabled. When inspecting the page, all of the OG tags are correct. These tags are injected using react-helmet.

https://browniepoints.africa/opportunities/volunteer-at-a-soup-kitchen-every-week-on-thursdays

When scraping the above URL on the Facebook debugger, it responds with:

```
The following required properties are missing: og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description, fb:app_id
```

The only one of those errors/warnings that should be there is the `app_id`, which I don't care about.

I've waited well over 48 hours for caches to clear, I've tried scraping with query strings appended to the URL, and the images have absolute URLs. But not even the description tag is pulling through.

Can somebody that uses react-helmet and Netlify please shed some definitive light onto this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to a known [prerendering issue](https://github.com/netlify/prerender/issues/20).

My fix was to remove the `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration from the `index.html` file as a temporary workaround until the above issue is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

While I can't tell you exactly why. your SSR is not working correctly. Go to Chrome DevTools and click the 3 vertical dots next to Console:

[image: Console options]

Select Networking Conditions, then uncheck Select Automatically and enter `Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)`:

[image: Network conditions]

Now refresh the page and notice that all you see on the site is some plaintext saying "html" and even your javascript bundle is missing. This is what your html looks like:

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="fragment" content="!">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
  <title>Brownie Points</title>
  <link href="/static/css/2.3bf0f3c5.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Note that Netlify SSR is in Beta but I personally didn't have those issues with it. Have you done any other steps other than enable it? I have tested it to be working with a CRA generated app before.

Comment: The user-agent and resulting broken HTML lead me to find the github thread in my answer with the bug workaround so I've awarded you the bounty.